# Objective C- Rotate a pointer in a circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, caanimation

I need to move an image around the edge of a circle image as the value changes. I tried this code as a sample to move in animation but no effect.

```
CGMutablePathRef path=CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL,image.frame.origin.x,image.frame.origin.y)
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path,NULL,image.frame.origin.x,image.frame.origin.y,pointer.frame.origin.x,pointer.frame.origin.y);

CAKeyframeAnimation *circle=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"circle"];
circle.path=path;
[circle setCalculationMode=kCAAnimationCubic];
[circle setFillMode=kCAFillModeForwards];
[pointer.layer addAnimation:circle forKey:nil];
```

`pointer` (`UIImage`) is the moveable object and `image` (`UIImage`) is the background image

Comment: Did you try to rotate with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` and change anchor point of layer?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the anchor point and then animate the `transform` property, e.g.

```
UIView *box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, boxSize.width, boxSize.height)];  // `origin` doesn't matter, because we'll set `center` below
box.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, radius / boxSize.height + 0.5);
box.center = center;   // this is the center of the arc
box.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
box.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( M_PI * 3.0 / 4.0, 0, 0, 1);
[self.view addSubview:box];

// note you could use `CABasicAnimation`, but I'd use `CAKeyframeAnimation` so that I control direction of animation

CAKeyframeAnimation *rotate = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger i = 3; i >= -3; i--) {
    [values addObject:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI * i / 4.0, 0, 0, 1)]];
}
rotate.values = values;

rotate.duration = 5.0;

[box.layer addAnimation:rotate forKey:@"rotateBox"];
```

[image]

Comment: box.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, radius / boxSize.height + 0.5); How can i find the radius here??

Comment: @Prarthana - In my example, it's the radius of my blue arc. In yours, it's the radius of the gray circle (or the radius of the gray circle plus half of the height of the image view of the graphic image that is being rotated).

Answer (score 0):

declare these as global

```
  tmax=100; 
  min=0;
  oldpsin=0;
```

on call of rotate

```
spin=valueToRotate*280.0/(max-min)*M_PI/180.0;
needle.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(needle.transform, spin-oldspin);
oldspin=spin ;
```

Thanks for all the helping hands.